# Assign Index inside a class using std::vector

Tags: c++, class, vector, operator-overloading, stdvector

I have a std::vector of 30 instances initialized like that:

```
#include <vector>

class Foo {
public:

    int x;
    int Index;  // I want this to be initialized when std::vector start the 
                // Instances.

    Foo(int& _x) : x(_x) {} 

    int Function(){
        // Do something cool ...
    }

};

int main(){

    int a = 5;
    std::vector<Foo> Instances (30, a);
    return 0;

}
```

So I want that when I call `std::vector<Foo> Instances (30, SomeVariablePassedByReference);` each member variable `Index` of each Instance get the corresponding number (0-30).

How can I accomplish that? Maybe using Operator Overloading? I don't want to use C-Stylish **[ ] operator**.

Comment: `&a` -- That is not a reference.  You are using the *address-of* operator, which returns a pointer.

Comment: yeah I was doing an example and I forgot that but I have edited that.

Comment: Sounds like you ought to use [`std::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate).

Comment: Remy Lebeau Ok man this is an example just edited the problem is not that...

Comment: all errors edited, sorry I did it too fast

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I was thinking the same thing, but the issue is that `std::generate()` takes two iterators as input, and you can't use `vector` iterators to access the members of the vector elements. The only way I can think of to make `std::generate()` work in this case is to either 1) use a `Generator` that returns successive `int` values starting at 0, and then give `Foo` an `operator=` that takes an `int` as input and assigns it to `Index`, or 2) derive a custom `iterator` that can iterate the `vector` but whose `operator*` returns a reference to `Foo::Index` instead of the `Foo` itself.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good point. What about [`std::generate_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) with [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)? Seems like a simple `mutable` closure could do the job.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `std::back_inserter` will push a new `Foo` object into the vector, so that would require `Foo` to have a constructor that takes a single `int` as input and assigns it to `Index`. But looking at the OP's definition of `Foo`, that would not be an option as then `x` is not initialized. Unless you used a `Generator` that returned a `std::pair`, and had a `Foo` constructor for that.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/k1qFWm ? Edit : Maybe capture `a` by reference since that's what `Foo::Foo` does, even if it later copies it. Edit 2 : With output : http://cpp.sh/2gbrc

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `std::iota`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a member variable of Foo to be the index within the vector?  Just call the ctor for each member and push it into the vector.

```
#include <vector>

class Foo {
public:

    int a;
    int Index;  // I want this to be initialized when std::vector start the 
                // Instances.

    Foo(int _index, int& _x) : Index(_index), a(_x) {} 

    void func(){
        // Do something cool ...
    }

};

int main(){

    int a = 5;
    std::vector<Foo> Instances;
    Instances.reserve(30);
    for(size_t i=0;i<30;i++)
       Instances.emplace_back(i,a);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: @MatthewFisher Only partially?

Comment: I think I have it now

Answer (score 2):

The value you pass in the 2nd parameter of `vector`'s constructor gets passed **as-is** to the copy constructor of each element that is created.  Since you are creating a `vector` of `Foo` objects, that second parameter will itself be a `Foo` object, so you are creating a temporary `Foo` with an `int` as input, and then that temporary is passed to the copy constructor of each `Foo` instance in the `vector`.

As such, the closest you could get with the syntax you are looking for is something like the following:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    ...
    int a;
    int Index;

    Foo(int _x) : a(_x), Index(-1) {} 
    Foo(const Foo &_f) : a(_f.a) { Index = ++(const_cast<Foo&>(_f).Index); } 
    ...
};

int main()
{
    int a = 5;

    // this (implicitly) creates a temp Foo object using the 'Foo(int)'
    // constructor, and then copy-constructs the Foo objects in the
    // vector passing that temp to the 'Foo(const Foo&)' constructor...
    std::vector<Foo> Instances (30, a);

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/7KI4Ju)

However, this is a **blatantly unsafe** misuse of the C++ language, so don't use it.

The safer option is to simply initialize the indexes after the `vector` is populated, eg:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    ...
    int a;
    int Index;

    Foo(int _x) : a(_x), Index(-1) {} 
    ...
};

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    std::vector<Foo> Instances (30, a);

    // yes, I know, you don't want to use the operator[], but it
    // is a safer option...
    for(size_t index = 0; index < Instances.size(); ++index)
        Instances[index].Index = index;

    // unless you use iterators instead...
    /*
    size_t index = 0;
    for (std::vector<Foo>::iterator iter = Instances.begin(); iter != Instances.end(); ++iter)
        iter->Index = index++;
    */
    /*
    size_t index = 0;
    for (auto &f : Instances)
        f.Index = index++;
    */

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/fork/7KI4Ju)

---

**Update**: thanks to [François Andrieux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7359094/fran%c3%a7ois-andrieux) in comments, I had another idea involving [`std::generate_n()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) to create the indexes for you the way you want.  Though it is not quite the syntax you are looking for:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

struct MyIndexGenerator
{
    int value;
    int index;

    MyIndexGenerator(int _value, int _first = 0) : value(_value), index(_first) {}

    std::pair<int, int> operator()()
    { 
        return std::make_pair(value, index++);
    }
};

class Foo
{
public:
    int x;
    int Index;

    Foo(const std::pair<int, int> &_x) : x(_x.first), Index(_x.second) {} 

    ...
};

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    std::vector<Foo> Instances;
    Instances.reserve(30);
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(Instances), 30, MyIndexGenerator(a));
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/S7e9c4)

Comment: @M.M In my first example, there is 1 `Foo` object being (implicitly) constructed in `main()`, and that *same object* will then be passed to the **copy**  constructor of every object in the vector. If I used what you say, every object in the vector would end up with the *same* `Index` value (0 in my example). The cast is necessary because a **copy** constructor *requires* its input parameter to be passed by const reference, and you can't normally modify the members of a `const` object. I'm updating the source object to increment its `Index` after every copy constructed from it

Comment: @M.M and yes, this is not a good use of a copy constructor. I stated as much in my answer. It does work *in this particular use-case*, but it should be avoided, yes.